# What is the URL for embedded LDAP server

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I need to use an Embedded server

```xml
<security:authentication-manager>   
    <security:ldap-authentication-provider  
                user-search-filter="(uid={0})" 
                user-search-base="ou=users"
                group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})"
                group-search-base="ou=groups"
                group-role-attribute="cn"
                role-prefix="ROLE_">
    </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>

<security:ldap-server ldif="classpath:mojo_working.ldif" root="dc=example,dc=com"  />
```

for custom populator.

its like

```xml
<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg ref="authenticator"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="populator"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="authenticator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource"/>
    <property name="userDnPatterns">
        <list>
            <value>uid={0},ou=users</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

In this  case what can be contextSource for Embedded LDAP Server.

Answer (score 2):

The `ldap-server` element creates a `ContextSource` so you don't need to define one. It [supports an id attribute](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-ldap-server), which you can use to create a reference to the bean.

```xml
<security:ldap-server id="embeddedServer" ... />

<bean id="authenticator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
    <constructor-arg ref="embeddedServer"/>
    ...
</bean>
```

So normally you don't need the URL. It also has a `port` element (default 33389), which you can set. The URL would be `ldap://localhost:33389/dc=example,dc=com` unless you set a different port.